# Problem in scraping youtube search results using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

```
url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={}".format(search_var)
url += """&sp=EgIQAQ%253D%253D"""
print(url)
r = requests.get(url)
r = r.text
print(r)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
# Getting the list of titles
links = soup.find_all('a', attrs={"class": "yt-uix-tile-link"})
titles = [i['title'] for i in links]
print(titles)
```

This method used to work around 3 months ago for extracting video titles from search results but it is not working now. The soup variable itself is not showing any information related to the page.
Please Help!

Comment: looks like YouTube has changed the page. You have to follow it.